# VS Code - Python file not running in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever i try to run a python file on vs code with the run python file button in the terminal it pastes this into the terminal

& C:/Users/FX505/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/FX505/OneDrive/Desktop/FP/Projeto1.py

however the python file does not run. i have the python extention installed. i have tried reinstalling python and vscode and still nothing.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What happens when the code "does not run"?

Comment: Right Click on python file, select open in integrated terminal, than in terminal type, py or python filename

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Comment: I am trying to run a python file with one function 

def is_pair(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")

what i think is happening is that the file is running however there is no way for me to input anything

Comment: Most probably your python interpreter location is not added to system PATH variable

Comment: I dont believe that is the case because when i type python into the terminal it opens python 3.10.7

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_pair(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Your code is a method definition, and has no practical application in the Python file. So you run the Python file only to load the method without displaying anything. If you want to run it, I have completed the following content for you, which you can modify as needed:

```
def is_pair(n):
    if int(n) % 2 == 0:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")


a=input()

is_pair(a)
```